# selecting random line from text file after deleting empty lines

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file which contains empty lines, I want to select a line except an empty line. Therefore, I tried to remove empty lines, select a random line and write into a text file. The file is like;

```
aaaa

bbbb


cccc
```

And output should be like;

```
bbbb
```

I can remove the empty lines using:

```
sed '/^\s*$/d' input.txt
```

And I can select a random line using:

```
echo $(shuf -n 1 input.txt) > output.txt
```

However, I cannot bring them together I used this, but did not work.

```
echo $(shuf -n 1 $(sed '/^\s*$/d' input.txt)) > output.txt
```

It gives an error for the second word of the line as `shuf: extra operand ‘someWord’`

Any help needed, thanks!

Comment: awk '/bbbb/' file is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does the output of your first sed command go?  Based on what you have, it goes to stdout.  It is definitely going to stdout within the $(...) sub-process.  This means they are written straight out to the outer sub-process as command line arguments.

The shuf command is trying to get something from stdin, not arguments from the command line.

What might work (I have not tried this), is to pipe.  Try this

```
sed '/^\s*$/d' input.txt | shuf -n 1 >output.txt
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `awk NF input.txt` is another terse way to remove empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a shell redirection, not a shell substitution:

```
echo $(shuf -n 1 <(sed '/^\s*$/d' input.txt)) > output.txt
```

In any case, that can be simplified a lot:

```
sed '/^\s*$/d' input.txt | shuf -n 1 > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a single `awk` command for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()} NF{row[++n]=$0} END{print row[int(rand() * n+1)]}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

one solution:

```
grep -v  '^$'  file | shuf -n 1 > output.txt
```